# How to overload the || operator to represent modulus of complex

Tags: c++

I would like to overload the || operator in such a way that I can use it to find the modulus of a complex number.
I.E.

```
    Complex z(x0,y0);
    double mod = |z|;
```

Is it possible to do so? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use the functions of the [complex type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), instead of creating new operators?

Comment: Is there any reason against creating a named function for modulo instead of using an operator?  If your function returns a reference, you could chain the calculation.

Answer (score 7):

No, that's not possible. There is no |x| operator (there is no such syntax). || is logical OR.

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to avoid writing code that attempts to change the **syntax** of C++ because it makes the code much less maintainable.  Imagine that you figured out a way to create a |x| operator (I don't think there's a way...).  The next person that read your code who knew C++ would have no idea what that was.